# What does "selective omission" means?

Tags: idioms

To choose which facts to say and which part of the truth to hide?(for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Else, it can mean "selective forgetting" (regarding social memory: erasing events from histories; hiding shameful episodes under the rug in hopes that as a nation/people, you can all forget about them).

In future, you may want to refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_omission) or a quick Google search for easy questions about definitions.